# Is there any library other than pyscopg2 that can be used to fetch the data from postgres db using python script?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, postgresql, rhel8

I have a requirement in the project which needs pandas, sqlalchemy and psycopg2 libraries. These are available in pypi.org but due to corporate compliance, I have to use only RHEL8. In RHEL8, I can find pandas, sqlalchemy but I couldn't find psycopg2. Is there any other library that I can use to fetch the data from postgres DB ?

Comment: `psycopg2` is a pure Python library and will run on any OS, including RHEL8. Just `pip install` it.

Comment: pg8000 - ref: https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/

Comment: Thank You. It helped @rajorshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psycopg2` [runs on RHEL8](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/postgresql-12-x86_64/python3-psycopg2-2.8.5-1.rhel8.x86_64.rpm.html).

Installation:

```sh
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But when i searched the same (yum search psycopg2) it is showing as no results found in my machine. And also, Do we have any python3-pandas library in RHEL7 ? Even this can solve my problem. I tried searching but couldn't find. I found  python-pandas.x86_64 in RHEL7 but this runs with python 2.7 not with 3.xx

Comment: `dnf install python3-pandas` ....... → the EPEL repo  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/  → https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/p/